# How to convert an IndexedTable to a DataFrame in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, type-conversion, julia

In a quick explanatory work, `IndexedTables` seem much faster than `DataFrames` to work on individual elements (e.g. select or "update"), but `DataFrames` have a nicer ecosystem of functionalities, e.g. plotting, exporting..

So, at a certain point of the workflow, I would like to convert the IndexedTable to a DataFrame, e.g.

```
using DataFrames, IndexedTables, IndexedTables.Table

tn = Table(
    Columns(
        param  = String["price","price","price","price","waterContent","waterContent"],
        item   = String["banana","banana","apple","apple","banana", "apple"],
        region = Union{String,DataArrays.NAtype}["FR","UK","FR","UK",NA,NA]
    ),
    Columns(
       value2000 = Float64[2.8,2.7,1.1,0.8,0.2,0.7],
       value2010 = Float64[3.2,2.9,1.2,0.8,0.2,0.8],
    )
)
```

to >>

```
df_tn = DataFrame(
    param     = String["price","price","price","price","waterContent","waterContent"],
    item      = String["banana","banana","apple","apple","banana", "apple"],
    region    = Union{String,DataArrays.NAtype}["FR","UK","FR","UK",NA,NA],
    value2000 = Float64[2.8,2.7,1.1,0.8,0.2,0.7],
    value2010 = Float64[3.2,2.9,1.2,0.8,0.2,0.8],
)
```

or

```
t = Table(
    Columns(
        String["price","price","price","price","waterContent","waterContent"],
        String["banana","banana","apple","apple","banana", "apple"],
        Union{String,DataArrays.NAtype}["FR","UK","FR","UK",NA,NA]
    ),
    Columns(
       Float64[2.8,2.7,1.1,0.8,0.2,0.7],
       Float64[3.2,2.9,1.2,0.8,0.2,0.8],
    )
)
```

to >>

```
df_t = DataFrame(
    x1 = String["price","price","price","price","waterContent","waterContent"],
    x2 = String["banana","banana","apple","apple","banana", "apple"],
    x3 = Union{String,DataArrays.NAtype}["FR","UK","FR","UK",NA,NA],
    x4 = Float64[2.8,2.7,1.1,0.8,0.2,0.7],
    x5 = Float64[3.2,2.9,1.2,0.8,0.2,0.8]
)
```

I can find the individual "row" values interacting over the table with `pair()`:

```
for (i,pair) in enumerate(pairs(tn))
    rowValues = []
    for (j,section) in enumerate(pair)
        for item in section
            push!(rowValues,item)
        end
    end
    println(rowValues)
end
```

I can't however get the columns names and types, and I guess working by column would instead be more efficient.

**EDIT :** I did manage to get the "column" types with the above code, I just need now to get the column names, if any:

```
colTypes = Union{Union,DataType}[]

for item in tn.index.columns
  push!(colTypes, eltype(item))
end
for item in tn.data.columns
  push!(colTypes, eltype(item))
end
```

**EDIT2**: As requested, this is an example of an IndexedTable that would fail conversion of columns names using (current) Dan Getz answer, as the "index" column(s) are named tuple but the "data" column(s) are normal tuples:

```
t_named_idx = Table(
    Columns(
        param  = String["price","price","price","price","waterContent","waterContent"],
        item   = String["banana","banana","apple","apple","banana", "apple"],
        region = Union{String,DataArrays.NAtype}["FR","UK","FR","UK",NA,NA]
    ),
    Columns(
       Float64[2.8,2.7,1.1,0.8,0.2,0.7],
    )
)
```

The problem seems to be in IndexedTable API, and specifically in `columns(t)` function, that doesn't distinguish between index and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following conversion functions:

```
toDataFrame(cols::Tuple, prefix="x") = 
  DataFrame(;(Symbol("$prefix$c") => cols[c] for c in fieldnames(cols))...)

toDataFrame(cols::NamedTuples.NamedTuple, prefix="x") = 
  DataFrame(;(c => cols[c] for c in fieldnames(cols))...)

toDataFrame(t::IndexedTable) = toDataFrame(columns(t))
```

give (on Julia 0.6 with `tn` and `t` defined as in the question):

```
julia> tn
param           item      region │ value2000  value2010
─────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────
"price"         "apple"   "FR"   │ 1.1        1.2
"price"         "apple"   "UK"   │ 0.8        0.8
"price"         "banana"  "FR"   │ 2.8        3.2
"price"         "banana"  "UK"   │ 2.7        2.9
"waterContent"  "apple"   NA     │ 0.7        0.8
"waterContent"  "banana"  NA     │ 0.2        0.2

julia> df_tn = toDataFrame(tn)
6×5 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ param          │ item     │ region │ value2000 │ value2010 │
├─────┼────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ 1   │ "price"        │ "apple"  │ "FR"   │ 1.1       │ 1.2       │
│ 2   │ "price"        │ "apple"  │ "UK"   │ 0.8       │ 0.8       │
│ 3   │ "price"        │ "banana" │ "FR"   │ 2.8       │ 3.2       │
│ 4   │ "price"        │ "banana" │ "UK"   │ 2.7       │ 2.9       │
│ 5   │ "waterContent" │ "apple"  │ NA     │ 0.7       │ 0.8       │
│ 6   │ "waterContent" │ "banana" │ NA     │ 0.2       │ 0.2       │
```

Type information is mostly retained:

```
julia> typeof(df_tn[:,1])
DataArrays.DataArray{String,1}

julia> typeof(df_tn[:,4])
DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1}
```

And for unnamed columns:

```
julia> t
───────────────────────────────┬─────────
"price"         "apple"   "FR" │ 1.1  1.2
"price"         "apple"   "UK" │ 0.8  0.8
"price"         "banana"  "FR" │ 2.8  3.2
"price"         "banana"  "UK" │ 2.7  2.9
"waterContent"  "apple"   NA   │ 0.7  0.8
"waterContent"  "banana"  NA   │ 0.2  0.2

julia> df_t = toDataFrame(t)
6×5 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x1             │ x2       │ x3   │ x4  │ x5  │
├─────┼────────────────┼──────────┼──────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ "price"        │ "apple"  │ "FR" │ 1.1 │ 1.2 │
│ 2   │ "price"        │ "apple"  │ "UK" │ 0.8 │ 0.8 │
│ 3   │ "price"        │ "banana" │ "FR" │ 2.8 │ 3.2 │
│ 4   │ "price"        │ "banana" │ "UK" │ 2.7 │ 2.9 │
│ 5   │ "waterContent" │ "apple"  │ NA   │ 0.7 │ 0.8 │
│ 6   │ "waterContent" │ "banana" │ NA   │ 0.2 │ 0.2 │
```

EDIT: As noted by @Antonello the case for mixed named and unnamed tuples is not handled correctly. To handle it correctly, we can define:

```
toDataFrame(t::IndexedTable) = 
  hcat(toDataFrame(columns(keys(t)),"y"),toDataFrame(columns(values(t))))
```

And then, the mixed case gives a result like:

```
julia> toDataFrame(tn2)
6×5 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ param          │ item     │ region │ x1  │ x2  │
├─────┼────────────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ "price"        │ "apple"  │ "FR"   │ 1.1 │ 1.2 │
│ 2   │ "price"        │ "apple"  │ "UK"   │ 0.8 │ 0.8 │
│ 3   │ "price"        │ "banana" │ "FR"   │ 2.8 │ 3.2 │
│ 4   │ "price"        │ "banana" │ "UK"   │ 2.7 │ 2.9 │
│ 5   │ "waterContent" │ "apple"  │ NA     │ 0.7 │ 0.8 │
│ 6   │ "waterContent" │ "banana" │ NA     │ 0.2 │ 0.2 │
```

Comment: It works faster than my solution (microseconds also for big datasets) and is obviously much more elegant, but when only one of {index, data} is a NamedTuple, all columns are converted to xi names. In general this answer teaches that it is better to look at one module's api than try to play with its interiors dumping an objecy.

Comment: I've noticed the problem with mixed named and non-named tuples, and in fact, an earlier iteration of the solution handled this well. This solution could also be tweaked a bit to handle it. I'll have a look.

Comment: Added an EDIT to the answer to handle the mixed case.

Comment: Works great (except that making a copy/paste there seems to be a [Zero-width non-joiner character](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiXm563mYTXAhXCtBoKHQj2D2gQFggxMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FZero-width_non-joiner&usg=AOvVaw2G78b7_hDzgw-NHK2C-GG8) thank you. It's a pity that the issue with "glue packages" linked by @Liso has not be solved, otherwise this should really go there..

Comment: Got rid of annoying invisible characters.

Comment: Just one minor note. With the modification to handle mixed case, now the converted df column names for unnamed IndexedTables in both the index/value would be {x1,x2,...,x1_1,x2_1,...}. One may want to add a `prefix=""` argument (unused) also to `toDataFrame(cols::NamedTuples.NamedTuple` and change `toDataFrame(t::IndexedTable) ` to `hcat(toDataFrame(columns(keys(t))),toDataFrame(columns(values(t)),"y"))`, so to have instead {x1,x2,...,y1,y2,...}

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, quick and dirty "solution" (I hope it is doable in other way):

```
julia> df = DataFrame(
         permutedims(  # <- structural transpose
           vcat(
             reshape([j for i in keys(t) for j in i], :, length(t)) , 
             reshape([j for i in t       for j in i], :, length(t))
           ), 
           (2,1)
         )
       )
6×5 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x1             │ x2       │ x3   │ x4  │ x5  │
├─────┼────────────────┼──────────┼──────┼─────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ "price"        │ "apple"  │ "FR" │ 1.1 │ 1.2 │
│ 2   │ "price"        │ "apple"  │ "UK" │ 0.8 │ 0.8 │
│ 3   │ "price"        │ "banana" │ "FR" │ 2.8 │ 3.2 │
│ 4   │ "price"        │ "banana" │ "UK" │ 2.7 │ 2.9 │
│ 5   │ "waterContent" │ "apple"  │ NA   │ 0.7 │ 0.8 │
│ 6   │ "waterContent" │ "banana" │ NA   │ 0.2 │ 0.2 │
```

Comment: thank you.. I'm "studying" it.. as it is, the converted df is made of `Any` columns and it doesn't store the eventual column names..

Answer (score 0):

Here it is an initial attampt to write a conversion function.. it keeps column names and type.. it would be nice if it could be cleaned up and implemented in either the DataFrame or the IndexedTable package as `convert(DataFrame,t::IndexedArray)`.

```
function toDataFrame(t::IndexedTable)

    # Note: the index is always a Tuple (named or not) while the data part can be a simple Array, a tuple or a Named tuple
          
    # Getting the column types.. this is independent if it is a keyed or normal IndexedArray
    colTypes = Union{Union,DataType}[]
    for item in t.index.columns
      push!(colTypes, eltype(item))
    end
    if(typeof(t.data) <: Vector)    # The Data part is a simple Array
        push!(colTypes, eltype(t.data))
    else                            # The data part is a Tuple
        for item in t.data.columns
          push!(colTypes, eltype(item))
        end
    end
    # Getting the column names.. this change if it is a keyed or normal IndexedArray
    colNames = Symbol[]
    lIdx  = length(t.index.columns)
    if(eltype(t.index.columns) <: AbstractVector) # normal Tuple
        [push!(colNames, Symbol("x",i)) for i in 1:lIdx]
    else                                          # NamedTuple
        for (k,v) in zip(keys(t.index.columns), t.index.columns)
            push!(colNames, k)
        end
    end
    if(typeof(t.data) <: Vector)    # The Data part is a simple single Array
        push!(colNames, Symbol("x",lIdx+1))
    else
        lData = length(t.data.columns)
        if(eltype(t.data.columns) <: AbstractVector)  # normal Tuple
            [push!(colNames, Symbol("x",i)) for i in (lIdx+1):(lIdx+lData)]
        else                                          # NamedTuple
            for (k,v) in zip(keys(t.data.columns), t.data.columns)
                push!(colNames, k)
            end
        end
    end
    # building an empty DataFrame..
    df = DataFrame()
    for i in 1:length(colTypes)
        df[colNames[i]] = colTypes[i][]
    end
    # and finally filling the df with values..
    for (i,pair) in enumerate(pairs(t))
        rowValues = []
        for (j,section) in enumerate(pair)
            for item in section
                push!(rowValues,item)
            end
        end
        push!(df, rowValues)
    end
    return df
end
```

EDIT 20210106:
Solution for NDSparse indexed table with a single value column:

```
# NDSparse creation...
content = [["banana","banana","apple","apple","orange"],["us",missing,"us","eu","us"],[1.1,2.2,3.3,missing,5.5]]
dimNames = ["item","region"]
t = NDSparse(content...,names=Symbol.(dimNames))

# NDSparse conversion to df...
names = vcat(keys(keys(t)[1])...,:value)
cols  = columns(t)
df    = DataFrame(map((n,v) -> Pair(n,v), names, cols))
```

Comment: Dan's solution  seems to be good. Did you test it? Is there problem if data is Vector?  BTW there is chance that we will have "glue" packages in future. See: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/2025#issuecomment-338005473

Comment: @Liso Ok, I gave it a try and the solution of Dan Gets works well (microseconds also for big datasets), except when only one of {index, data} is a NamedTuple, for which all columns are converted to xi names.

Comment: Can you add small example where it doesn't work with column names?

Comment: @Liso added.. note that my ugly solution still works in all cases.. but.. it's ugly ;-) (and slower that Dan Gets answer)

Answer (score 0):

Just install IterableTables and then

```
using IterableTables
df = DataFrames.DataFrame(it)
```

Comment: Nice to hear about IterableTables (and require.jl !), but it converts only if the source is reducible to a named tuple. In my example, it works with `tn` but not (at least, without preliminary conversions) with `t`.